# Wagtail - how to access StructBlock class attribute inside block

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to override my block template as described here:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3857

I added a BooleanBlock inside the class and tried to use that value to change the template but I get an error "no attribute found".

```
class Features_Block(StructBlock):
    title = CharBlock()
    description = TextBlock(required=False)

    use_other_template = BooleanBlock(default=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        icon = 'list-ul'

    def get_template(self, context=None):
        if self.use_other_template:
            return 'other_template.html'

        return 'original_template.html'
```

I have found this thread which might be the answer but I don't understand how to implement it for my case:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4387

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get_template` method doesn't receive the block's value as a parameter, so there's no reliable way to vary the chosen template according to that value. You might be able to dig around in the calling template's context to retrieve the block value, as in Matt's answer, but this means the internals of `Features_Block` will be tied to the use of particular variable names in the calling template, which is a bad thing for reusable code.

(Accessing `self.use_other_template` doesn't work because `self`, the `Features_Block` object, doesn't hold on to the block value as a property of itself - it only serves as a translator between different representations. So, it knows how to render a given dictionary of data as HTML, but that dictionary of data is not something that 'belongs' to the `Features_Block`.)

`get_template` is called from [the block's `render` method](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/70a749b10a1b0c4dac527da28e54cbb3581a774e/wagtail/core/blocks/base.py#L231-L246), which *does* receive the block value, so overriding `render` will allow you to vary the template based on the block value:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class Features_Block(StructBlock):

    # ...

    def render(self, value, context=None):
        if value['use_other_template']:
            template = 'other_template.html'
        else:
            template = 'original_template.html'

        if context is None:
            new_context = self.get_context(value)
        else:
            new_context = self.get_context(value, parent_context=dict(context))

        return mark_safe(render_to_string(template, new_context))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `context` that's passed to `get_template`.

```py
class Features_Block(StructBlock):
    title = CharBlock()
    description = TextBlock(required=False)

    use_other_template = BooleanBlock(default=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        icon = 'list-ul'

    def get_template(self, context=None):
        if context and context['block'].value['use_other_template']:
            return 'other_template.html'

        return 'original_template.html'
```

Comment: What do I send as context in this case? I'm getting: 'BlockNode' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: FWIW, I'm calling this block in my template by "value.title" and "value.description".