# Wagtail: Rendering tags from Fieldblock

Tags: tags, wagtail

I am really stuck on this: (sorry, newbie problems)
Following the method [exposed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875597/wagtail-how-to-access-structblock-class-attribute-inside-block) I need to render the tags in a page, but I am not able to get the tag values through the @property

The code is as follow, the models:

```
class TagsBlock(blocks.FieldBlock):
    """
    Basic Stream Block that will use the Wagtail tags system.
    Stores the tags as simple strings only.
    """

    def __init__(self, required=False, help_text=None, **kwargs):
        # note - required=False is important if you are adding this tag to an existing streamfield
        self.field = forms.CharField(widget=AdminTagWidget, required=False)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
  

class ServicesPage(Page):
    
    services = StreamField([
        ('services',blocks.StructBlock([
            ('entries',PortfolioBlock()),
            ('tags',TagsBlock(required=False)),
    ]))], null=True, blank=True)
    
    @property
    def get_tags(self):
        """
        Helpful property to pull out the tags saved inside the struct value
        Important: makes some hard assumptions about the names & structure
        Does not get the id of the tag, only the strings as a list
        """

        tags_all = [block.value.entries.get('tags', '').split(',') for block in self]

        tags = list(chain.from_iterable(tags_all))

        return tags
    
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('services'),

    ]
```

Then in the template im just doing:

```
         <div class="row-4">
            
            {% for tag in page.services.get_tags %}
               {{tag}}
            {% endfor %}

          </div>
```

However, I can't get any result. I have really tried everything, but I can't figure how to call the property to give me the list of values.

Thank you very much in advance for your time,

Francisco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, the line

```
{% for tag in page.services.get_tags %}
```

would be trying to access a property named `get_tags` on the 'services' field of the page. However, `get_tags` isn't defined there - it's defined as a property of the page object - so this line should be

```
{% for tag in page.get_tags %}
```

Secondly, in the line

```
tags_all = [block.value.entries.get('tags', '').split(',') for block in self]
```

you're intending to loop over all the items in the StreamField, but the `self` in `for block in self` refers to the page object. This should be `for block in self.services`.

Finally, in the same line, `block.value` will give you the value of each block, which in this case will be a dictionary of two items, `entries` and `tags`. If you wanted to access `entries` (the PortfolioBlock), you would write `block.value['entries']` or `block.value.get('entries')` rather than `block.value.entries` - but really you don't want that, you want to access the `tags` item instead - so `block.value.entries.get('tags', '').split(',')` should be `block.value.get('tags', '').split(',')`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply !!. It works. I did lot of trial-and-error but what I never got was the "self.services". Now I need just to define the filters to filter posts by tag.